# How do i get the month names in between two dates using Java

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to find out the month names from `01/01/2014` to `12/28/2014` in the format of "`MMM`, `YY`". But i'm getting the below output.

```
DEC, 14. 
JAN, 14. 
FEB, 14. 
MAR, 14. 
APR, 14. 
MAY, 14. 
JUN, 14. 
JUL, 14. 
AUG, 14. 
SEP, 14. 
OCT, 14. 
NOV, 14.
```

I Need an output like this

```
Jan, 14
.......
.......
Dec, 14
```

Can anyone help on this.

Here is my code.

```
    String date1 = "01/01/2014";
    String date2 = "12/28/2014";
    final String OLD_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMM, YY";  
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
    Date fromDate = newFormat.parse(date1);
    Date toDate = newFormat.parse(date2);
    newFormat.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
    String newFromDate = newFormat.format(fromDate);
    String newToDate = newFormat.format(toDate);
    //System.out.println(newFromDate);
    //System.out.println(newToDate);
    DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(NEW_FORMAT);

    Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        beginCalendar.setTime(formater.parse(newFromDate));
        finishCalendar.setTime(formater.parse(newToDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String date;
    while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
        // add one month to date per loop
         date =   formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(date);
        beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: Why do you do `toUpperCase` when you want normal case month names?

Comment: Actually newFromDate="Jan, 14" but when you parse with formatter begin calendar becomes 28.12.2013. I dont get it. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
    String date1 = "01/01/2014";
    String date2 = "12/28/2014";
    final String OLD_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMM, YY";
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(NEW_FORMAT);
    Date fromDate = newFormat.parse(date1);
    Date toDate = newFormat.parse(date2);

    Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    beginCalendar.setTimeInMillis(fromDate.getTime());
    finishCalendar.setTimeInMillis(toDate.getTime());

    String date;
    while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
        // add one month to date per loop
        date = formatter.format(beginCalendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }
```

Comment: @vsreekanth can you accept the solution that fix your problem please?

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The new classes include [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for working with a date-only value *sans* time-of-day and time zone. From there we will use [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) objects since you are interested in, well, year and month.

First parse your two strings into a pair of `LocalDate` instances.

```
String inputStart = "01/01/2014";
String inputStop = "12/28/2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse ( inputStart , formatterInput );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse ( inputStop , formatterInput );
```

We are going to generate String representations of our `YearMonth` objects. The default format for the `YearMonth::toString` method is the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM. I strongly suggest using these formats whenever practicable. But your Question specified a different format, so we must define a custom formatter pattern.

Note the explicit `Locale` object, such as `Locale.ENGLISH` or `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`. If omitted your JVM’s current default locale is implicitly applied to localize the month name. The default can change at any moment, *during runtime*, so I recommend always specifying your desired/expected locale.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMM yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH );  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc.
```

Rather than use `System.out.println`, let’s collect the String output for each month in a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

```
List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<> ();
```

Instantiate a `YearMonth` for our starting LocalDate.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from ( start );
```

From that starting yearMonth, loop a sequence of YearMonth objects, generating a String representation of that year-month value. Continue looping until we increment past the year-month of the ending `LocalDate`. In each loop we increment by calling [`plusMonths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#plusMonths-long-).

```
// Repeat while the current year-month is *not* after (is before or is equal) the ending year-month.
while (  ! yearMonth.isAfter ( YearMonth.from ( stop ) ) ) {
    //String output = yearMonth.toString ();  // ISO 8601 format.
    String output = yearMonth.format ( formatter );
    outputs.add ( output );
    // Prepare for next loop.
    yearMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths ( 1 );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "Months from start: " + start + " to stop: " + stop + " is: " + outputs );
```

> Months from start: 2014-01-01 to stop: 2014-12-28 is: [Jan 2014, Feb 2014, Mar 2014, Apr 2014, May 2014, Jun 2014, Jul 2014, Aug 2014, Sep 2014, Oct 2014, Nov 2014, Dec 2014]

I strongly recommend against using two-digit year numbers as output. I have found such abbreviated years causes confusion in a business. But if you insist, adjust the pattern to `yy` from `yyyy`.

Tip: Since `YearMonth` is built into Java 8 and later, I suggest using objects of this class throughout your code if you are doing more with year-month values than just dumping the month names as seen in your Question.

This code could be made more robust. For example, check that the ending LocalDate is indeed `isEqual` or `isAfter` (not `isBefore`) the starting one. You might be able to optimize a bit by holding the result of `YearMonth.from ( stop )` in a variable rather than calling repeatedly in the loop, but I would not bother unless you used this code *very* often – and the JVM might well optimize that for you automatically.